# How to remove old kernel versions?

Tags: kernel, updates

How can I remove old kernels after upgrading to a new version?

It is annoying me to have these kernel entries in the Grub boot menu.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu

Comment: **You may need to run:** sudo rm -rf /lib/modules/<_unused_kernels_modules_dirs_> **...after using these techniques**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is always recommended to leave the 2 latest versions of the kernel, but to remove other kernel versions I used the following commands:

```
dpkg -l | fgrep linux-image-
```

[image: A list of the kernels installed should appear]

Never remove the kernel shown in `uname -r` or `linux-image-generic-lts-utopic`.

Finally `sudo apt-get purge <package names>` for the kernels you want to remove (see screenshot for reference).

Then `sudo update-grub` to update the Bootloader.

Comment: was apprehensive about remove linux-image-generic-lts-utopic, for now it hasn't given any problem, but maybe refrain from removing it.

Comment: That is the meta-package that pulls in the latest updates, you won't receive new kernel patches without it.

Comment: Thank you, edited to reflect that.
If anyone has removed this package, 
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic
should fix it

Comment: BTW, only 1 ` is needed at each end of the code, not 3.

Answer (score 13):

You can use this one-liner to automatically clean up all old kernels (**make sure to restart the computer before doing this if you have just updated the kernel**):

`sudo apt purge $( dpkg --list | grep -P -o "linux-(headers|image)-\d\S+" | grep -v $(uname -r | grep -P -o ".+\d") )`

What it does is uninstall (`apt purge`) the installed packages (`dpkg --list`) whose names match "linux-headers-[number]" or "linux-image-[number]" (`grep -P -o "linux-(headers|image)-\d\S+"`), except (`grep -v`) those corresponding to the current kernel version (`uname -r | grep -P -o ".+\d"`).

---

Sources:

- [CommandLineFu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5813/remove-all-unused-kernels-with-apt-ge) - the original inspiration
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176322/removing-old-kernel-entries-in-grub#answer-196437) - using apt’s "purge" rather than "remove")
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18804/what-do-the-various-dpkg-flags-like-ii-rc-mean) - ensuring the entries returned could be safely removed
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901171/is-d-not-supported-by-greps-basic-expressions) - using PCRE in `grep` (`\d`, `\S`, etc) and using the `-P` option
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/274981/return-only-pattern-matched-string-from-grep) - using `-o` to make `grep` return only the matched content

Comment: What about `linux-image-extra`? Thanks.

Comment: @JinKwon those [appear to be](http://askubuntu.com/a/153033/23900) less commonly installed, but you can just replace `"linux-(headers|image)-\d\S+"` with `"linux-(headers|image(-extra)?)-\d\S+"` and the command will include them as well.

Comment: I've added a few more packages to this command to clean out modules and modules-extra: 


`sudo apt purge $( dpkg --list | grep -P -o "linux-(headers|image|modules|modules-extra)-\d\S+" | grep -v $(uname -r | grep -P -o ".+\d") )`

Answer (score 8):

You can simply run

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

to "remove all unused packages" which includes older kernels.

You should test a reboot before to be shure the new kernel works!

It is more secure to leave the 2 latest versions as John pointed out in his answer.

Comment: Unfortunately autoremove does not remove orphaned kernel versions by default, for the very reason that they may be needed should one not work, but they can be passed in by package name as detailed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels

Comment: @LewisGoddard you are right. i tested it today. i thought i had done that in the past. so i delete my answer. the accepted answer works well

Comment: on a 32-bit system i could remove older kernels with `apt-get autoremove`. i installed 3.16.0-43, had -41 installed and got a suggestion to autoremove 38, 39. it also updated the grub config. so maybe it is also not necessary to do it manually with the tasks on the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Removing old kernels:

(I suggest boot to latest kernel)

---

**Remove Manually**:

First list current kernel:

```
uname -r
```

Example output:`3.19.0-28-generic`

To list all kernels :

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Now purge old kernels manually,(be sure don't purge current kernel)

For example:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.16.0-34 linux-image-3.16.0-46 linux-image-3.16.0-48 linux-image-3.16.0-49
```

**Note**: In general to remove old kernels use `linux-image-x.x.x-x` where replace x with numbers.

---

**Automatic**:

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve "$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//')")
```

**Note**: you can verify deleting kernels with following command-here the output **excludes current loaded/running kernel** .So please boot to latest kernel.

```
kernelver=$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//')
dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve $kernelver
```

Reference [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels)

---

Answer (score 2):

To remove old kernels you can also use `synaptic`:

To install synaptic:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Now open synaptic and search for `linux-image` under `installed` tab as shown and then

Right click on selected old kernel and select `mark for complete removal`

---

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

---

**Note**: Screenshots are only examples from my system.I already deleted old kernels.Please select old kernels as per your system.

---

Answer (score 2):

UKUU is a good GUI based tool for managing kernels

```
 sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install ukuu
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a simpler way:

```
sudo apt install byobu
sudo purge-old-kernels
```

that's all, it will leave 2 kernel versions and remove all others

Comment: Why byobu? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Just because the command/script `purge-old-kernels` is included in the byobu package and `byobu` is installed by default on Ubuntu server

Comment: I've found that running `sudo apt autoremove --purge` removes also older kernels and leave only one or two versions after clean-up.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I was having the same problem with ElementaryOS. This is the Terminal command I ran to solve the problem:

```
sudo apt purge $( dpkg --list | grep -P -o "linux-(headers|image)-\d\S+" | grep -v $(uname -r | grep -P -o ".+\d") )
```