# How can I clean the system from unnecessary files?

Tags: system

How can I safely clean the system from unnecessary files to free up disk space? I mean unnecessary packages, configs, cache, etc.

Answer (score 17):

Remove packages that were automatically
installed to satisfy dependencies for some package and that are no
more needed:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Clear out the local repository of retrieved package files:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Remove all files associated with removed packages (if you don’t have aptitude installed do `sudo apt-get install aptitude`):

```
sudo aptitude purge ~c
```

Remove old kernel versions (thank @waldyrious for [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/117)):

```
sudo apt-get purge $( dpkg --list | grep -P -o "linux-(headers|image)-\d\S+" | grep -v $(uname -r | grep -P -o ".+\d") )
```

Clear the thumbnail cache:

```
rm -v -f ~/.cache/thumbnails/*/*.png ~/.thumbnails/*/*.png
```

Comment: You can also find useful gCleaner app, in development for elementary OS https://launchpad.net/gcleaner

Answer (score 9):

CCleaner is not directly available for elementary. You can use `BleachBit` for this purpose.

Install `bleachbit` from software center.

[image: Imgur]

If you are comfortable with terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
```

Comment: This is good.  I tried to install ccleaner by installing wine and followed by ccleaner  Windows setup. But that is not helpful for the Linux.  Thanks for finding alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Linux remove unuseful files automaticly way more than windows. An app like CCleaner for windows will not have much work and it is unuseful I think.

It can still detect a very few mistakes, remove the data of your programs (reset them, useful especially if you have got chrome wich stores about 2 GB on my computer even if I am nearly not using it), and see if you have got the same file 2 times at a different place.

You have a few equivalents including bleachbit (supposed to be the best, haven't tried it), you can also use SystemCleanUpTool, fslint and GTKOrphan.

Answer (score 0):

Use Resetter app from This site https://github.com/gaining/Resetter