# System fonts broken on Hera

Tags: release-hera, plank, pantheon, fonts

I'm running eOS 5.1.6 Hera on Dell XPS 13 (9300) as daily driver and am really enjoying it. That said, after a reboot today the system-wide fonts got completely broken and show as rectangles everywhere in system menus.

I tried a bunch of solutions previously suggested, including:

- Reinstalling elementary-tweaks/elementary-desktop
- Resetting the fonts
- Changing settings of screenshot tool (since there used to be a bug related to it)

I also rebooted system multiple times after each of those attempts. I did not install any specific apps since prior to the issue, but might have updated `apt`. Just in case, I was using Inter fonts as system fonts and dark UI theme installed using elementary tweaks and the hack proposed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/gxhsi9/slowly_losing_dark_theme_with_each_update/).

In addition, when I go to the elementary tweaks interface and try to change the fonts there, the tweaks fail and close immediately. I also noticed that the pre-installed Fonts app does not show any fonts, but the font-manager I installed myself shows the fonts (though the interface and menus fonts are still broken). Also, interestingly, when I login as guest the fonts show up properly, but the Pantheon desktop stops working when I try to use any system interface.

I would really appreciate any help with this issue, since I'm new to eOS and wanted to use it as a daily driver, but this issue makes it completely unusable.

### UPDATE: Issue solved

**I actually managed to resolve the issue myself by rebuilding the font cache by running `sudo fc-cache -f -v` in the terminal session. Still not sure exactly what caused the issue, but this restored all the fonts and now everything works properly.**

Comment: Juno is not the latest version of Elementary OS. The latest is Hera.

Comment: @Sysadmin , yes, you're totally right, I am running Hera. Corrected the title.

Comment: Nothing wrong with answering your own question, but it would be helpful to put the answer in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try also to rebuild font cache by typing in terminal:

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

Comment: Yes, this solved it for me. Thank you for all the proposed solutions!

Comment: I am glad. I provided other solutions. Maybe it will help others if they will have an issue with fonts. Please upvote this one solution with rebuilding font cache.

Comment: I did, but I don't have enough reputation to make it publicly visible yet. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Access the terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F1 and type:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall elementary-desktop
sudo systemctl reboot
```

Comment: I tried this approach, the desktop app was reinstalled successfully and the fonts were reset to default values (confirmed by calling `gsettings get`). Still the issue persists and none of the system fonts work.

Comment: The question is, do you have important data on the system? I recommend to make a backup and then install the system from the scratch. I really have no idea what happened and why it behaves like you described.

Comment: I can definitely reinstall from scratch, but I wanted to try and understand what caused the issue, given that it started out of blue and there is no guarantee it won't happen again after I spend hours reinstalling and setting up the apps.

Comment: Try perform and upgrade:

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean -y

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling Elementary OS desktop open terminal and type:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name            

gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface document-font-name 

gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name

gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences titlebar-font 

gsettings reset org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font 

gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this by type the command in terminal:

```
sudo tail /var/log/dpkg.log
```

and provide the results here.

Also command:

```
sudo journalctl -xb
```

Will contain information.

Additionally you can check what you have installed by typing:

```
sudo tail -n 50 /var/log/apt/history.log
```

Also worth to check this:

```
sudo tail /var/log/fontconfig.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread: [ttps://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13499/elementary-os-system-fonts-haywire](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13499/elementary-os-system-fonts-haywire)

Click the Application on the wingpanel (top left), type screenshot , run it, and switch the switcher Conceal text to disable it.

[image: Screenshot app]

Answer (score 0):

You can also create additionally a new user in the system and check do fonts displaying correctly or not by logging to the new user account.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution is to install BleachBit and run it as standard user not as a root.

[How can I clean the system from unnecessary files?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/how-can-i-clean-the-system-from-unnecessary-files)

Select options I highlighted on the screenshot.

[image: BleachBit user settings]

After that run BleachBit as root from Applications. If it will not run, open terminal and type

```
sudo bleachbit
```

And select as below on the image.

[image: BleachBit as root]