# Boot partition low space warnings - problems doing updates [tried another similar post but didn't work]

Tags: system

On starting OS and when I try to update and install stuff I get the error *boot partition low space*

I've been having lots of issues with freya so I'd like to get stuff running smoothly.

Partition scheme I have

boot: around 300Mb
root: around 30/35Gb
Home: more than 100Gb
Swap: 10Gb (around 1.5 my RAM)

As advised in lots of guides

Boot partition is full. Why are kernel files pilling up in the partition? Shouldn't they swap when upgrading? Will this always happen once in a while? What files to delete? PlayOnLinux added lots of crap on terminal when I tried to use another question solution

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have more **unused** kernels:(Open terminal and run the commands)

(I suggest boot to latest kernel)

---

**Remove Manually**:

First list current kernel:

```
uname -r
```

Example output:`3.19.0-28-generic`

To list all kernels :

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Now purge old kernels manually,(be sure don't purge current kernel)

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.16.0-34 linux-image-3.16.0-46 linux-image-3.16.0-48 linux-image-3.16.0-49
```

Note: In general to remove old kernels use `linux-image-x.x.x-x` where replace x with numbers.

---

**Automatic**:

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve "$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//')")
```

**Note**: you can verify deleting kernels with following command-here the output **excludes current loaded/running kernel** .So please boot to latest kernel.

```
kernelver=$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//')
dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve $kernelver
```

Reference [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels)

---

**Alternative**

You can also use `synaptic`:

To install `synaptic`:

```
 sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

please refer [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/95/how-to-remove-old-kernel-versions/2468#2468)

---