# elementary OS disk space getting low

Tags: release-freya

Not sure anyone on the dev team will get this but I just wanted to say I really like elementary OS. I do a lot of php app development with my acer aspire one (8GB SSD) and when I was looking for a lightweight Linux OS for my netbook I found elementary OS. But with every update it grows bigger. The computer says I have 60MB left. This is sad because now I have to look for another lightweight os and start over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably kernel updates that are eating your SSD space. Regular updates just replace apps with newer version but kernel is so crucial that if something goes wrong in the new version you can be unable to boot your machine. For this reason old kernels are kept in the system so you have always working kernel to boot from.

You can check how many kernels you have and if this is your case by running in terminal e.g.:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

You can also check what eats most space with apps like [baobab](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/baobab/) or [GdMap](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/gdmap/).

Now you can remove those older kernels and keep only the last two (recommended for the reasons above). On Ubuntu the [most recommended way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) is to install Ubuntu Tweak, however this might not be the optimal way on elementary OS. You can try installing [synaptic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/) and remove old kernels manually or try some terminal scripts (one example can be found on [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2240697)).

But before doing anything I recommend doing a bit of reading on this topic here at [StackExchange/AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) to get an idea what's going on.

**In Loki:**

Thanks to upstream fix apt autoremove now properly removes old kernels so you can use

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

to remove all unnecessary packages, including old kernels. It's also good idea to run

```
sudo apt autoclean
```

once in a while.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu Tweak will cause issues because it depends on Unity. It pulls in extra packages and will alter LightDM

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Didn't want to install anything else so I used `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-` to list all kernels and `uname - r` to figure out latest. Then used `sudo apt-get autoremove list-of-unwanted-kernels`. Found instructions here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels

Comment: Great :) and to @DanielForé I didn't know for sure so I went with "not optimal". Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @DanielForé It was bugging me at the back of my head a little bit - is it possible you confused `ubuntu-tweak` with `unity-tweak-tool`? Because I just checked (with `apt-cache showpkg ubuntu-tweak`) and it does not depend on Unity. Ubuntu Tweak is not in repos (installs as deb package) while Unity tweak tool is in repos (and does depend on Unity). I succesfully used Ubuntu Tweak in e.g. Xubuntu and PeppermintOS without noticable issues - certainly no Unity dependencies were pulled in. It might not be optimal for elementaryOS, but I wanted to set the record staight.

Answer (score 6):

- `baobab` will let you figure out what files and folders are taking up all the space on your hard drive.

  Install `baobab` with the command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install baobab
  ```

  Select any file from the table on the left side to move it to trash on right click.

  [image: img]
- To remove old kernels follow the post:

  [How to remove old kernel versions?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2467/2708)

  [Boot partition low space warnings - problems doing updates](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1986/boot-partition-low-space-warnings-problems-doing-updates-tried-another-simila)
- To remove unnecessary files:

  [How can I clean the system from unnecessary files?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/how-can-i-clean-the-system-from-unnecessary-files?lq=1)