# Low disk space on file system

Tags: release-freya, apt, kernel, disk-management, filesystem

Low disk space on file system message on:

- Elementary: `elementary OS Freya (64-bit)` Built on "Ubuntu 14.04
  LTS"
- File manager: `Files 0.2.4`

I want to create more disk space and running the command `df-h` gives the following output:

```
Filesystem  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           390M  1.2M  389M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        19G   18G  637M  97% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G   78M  1.9G   4% /run/shm
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1       823G   31G  751G   4% /home
```

I can't install any programs as there is no space on `/dev/sda1`, so I cannot install a program with a user interface to view files.

Therefore we took the following route:

So, the first disk is very small, and **Plan A** is just to free up enough stuff on it to stop it moaning. **Plan B** would he to move some stuff over to the spacious disk, and link it in. But hopefully A will work!

I reckon there's a lot of unused kernel images in `/boot`, it seeks to get a known weakness with elementary that it doesn't tidy old ones up. I had a web page up that described how to remove them and then update the grub menu so it didn't offer them anymore. But the first command was giving a funny error. I'm following the suggestions on this page:

[How to remove old kernel versions?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/95/how-to-remove-old-kernel-versions)

---

So, we ran this command:

```
dpkg -l | fgrep linux-image-
```

It will list a lot of kernel images, most of which you aren't actively using. They're all similarly named, differentiated by a numerical suffix e.g. "`.151`" To find out which one you are using when you boot up, run this:

```
uname -r
```

The result was an old kernel image: `3.13.0-44-generic`

We are assuming that any other kernel images newer than this can go:

So starting with `3.13.0-45-generic`

```
$ sudo su 
# apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic
# exit
```

Running this command produced the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet de pendencies:
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0-151-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
#
```

I ran `apt-get -f install` but not sure if I should now run `apt-get autoremove` - I guess there will be a net gain of disk space that will accommodate the 13.5MB need for the new installations?

```
# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libgconf2-4 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin
  libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libidl-common libidl0
  libntdb1 liborbit-2-0 liborbit2 libqpdf13 linux-headers-3.13.0-105
  linux-headers-3.13.0-105-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-116
  linux-headers-3.13.0-116-generic linux-image-3.13.0-105-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-116-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-105-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-116-generic python-ntdb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-151-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-151-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/706 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] apt-get -f install
```

Then running this command:

```
# apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0-151-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

...

```
# apt-get -f install
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Correcting dependencies... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libgconf2-4 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin
      libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libidl-common libidl0
      libntdb1 liborbit-2-0 liborbit2 libqpdf13 linux-headers-3.13.0-105
      linux-headers-3.13.0-105-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-116
      linux-headers-3.13.0-116-generic linux-image-3.13.0-105-generic
      linux-image-3.13.0-116-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-105-generic
      linux-image-extra-3.13.0-116-generic python-ntdb
    Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
    The following extra packages will be installed:
      linux-headers-3.13.0-151-generic
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      linux-headers-3.13.0-151-generic
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
    2 not fully installed or removed.
    Need to get 0 B/706 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 13.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
    Abort.
```

---

```
After this operation, 13.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] yes

(Reading database ... 1223843 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.13.0-151 generic_3.13.0-151.201_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.13.0-151-generic (3.13.0-151.201) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-151-generic_3.13.0-151.201_amd64.deb (--unpack):
error creating symbolic link `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-151-generic/include/linux/if_arp.h': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error

Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-151-generic_3.13.0-151.201_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
$
```

---

---

```
$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

<1> dpkg --list | grep linux-image

### https://pastebin.com/NQChqwir

```
$ sudo du -h / -d 1 --exclude=/home
[sudo] password: 
8.0K    /media
0   /sys
15M /sbin
4.0K    /cdrom
16K /lost+found
du: cannot access ‘/proc/3069/task/3069/fd/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/3069/task/3069/fdinfo/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/3069/fd/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/3069/fdinfo/3’: No such file or directory
0   /proc
1.3G    /var
300K    /tmp
68K /root
4.0K    /mnt
31M /etc
7.1G    /lib
4.0K    /lib64
4.0K    /opt
4.0K    /dev
1.4G    /boot
4.0K    /srv
du: cannot access ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
1.4M    /run
9.7M    /bin
```

---

```
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             484K   539  483K    1% /dev
tmpfs            488K   550  487K    1% /run
/dev/sda1        1.2M  1.2M  8.9K  100% /
none             488K     2  488K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             488K     3  488K    1% /run/lock
none             488K    45  488K    1% /run/shm
none             488K    24  488K    1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1         53M   42K   53M    1% /home
```

---

```
# for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
/bin
154
/boot
504
/cdrom
1
/dev
546
/etc
2911
/home
42341
/initrd.img
1
/initrd.img.old
1
/lib
175661
/lib32
44
/lib64
2
/lost+found
1
/media
2
/mnt
1
/opt
1
/proc
109901
/root
17
/run
571
/sbin
211
/srv
1
/sys
29272
/tmp
20
/usr
1051276
/var
10966
/vmlinuz
1
/vmlinuz.old
1
# exit
```

---

I am uncertain but I may have missed a step.  First line in step 4 (after you ran du on /) has this already been completed?

```
$ sudo du -h /lib/ -d 1 --exclude=/home
[sudo] password for gary: 
52K /lib/recovery-mode
220K    /lib/plymouth
17M /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
8.0K    /lib/ifupdown
12K /lib/apparmor
16K /lib/hdparm
8.0K    /lib/modules-load.d
6.9G    /lib/modules
12K /lib/linux-sound-base
175M    /lib/firmware
8.0K    /lib/nvidia-340
1.3M    /lib/xtables
140K    /lib/modprobe.d
32K /lib/lsb
880K    /lib/systemd
768K    /lib/brltty
16K /lib/resolvconf
208K    /lib/terminfo
36K /lib/ufw
11M /lib/udev
20K /lib/init
28K /lib/crda
7.1G    /lib/
:~$
```

---

$ sudo du -h /lib/modules/* -d 1
    [sudo] password:

2> $ sudo du -h /lib/modules/* -d 1

https://pastebin.com/U65EfV7P

---

<3> $ ls -la /lib/modules/

https://pastebin.com/u8m3WctC

total 152

---

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-44-generic
```

---

```
:~$ awk -F\' '/menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
elementary OS
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-151-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-151-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-149-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-149-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-147-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-147-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-145-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-145-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-144-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-144-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-143-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-143-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-142-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-142-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-141-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-141-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-139-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-139-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-137-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-137-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-135-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-135-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-133-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-133-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-132-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-132-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-129-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-129-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-128-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-128-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-126-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-126-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-125-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-125-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-123-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-123-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-121-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-121-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-119-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-119-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-117-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-117-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-116-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-116-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-115-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-115-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-113-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-113-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-112-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-110-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-110-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-108-generic        
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-108-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-107-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-107-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-106-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-106-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-105-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-101-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-101-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-85-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-74-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-74-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-57-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-57-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-45-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-45-generic (recovery mode)
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-44-generic
elementary OS, with Linux 3.13.0-44-generic (recovery mode)
Memory test (memtest86+)
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
```

---

```
:~$ sudo su
: 
# for i in /usr/*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
/usr/bin
1369
/usr/games
8
/usr/include
1334
/usr/lib
18577
/usr/lib32
308
/usr/local
29
/usr/sbin
201
/usr/share
144962
/usr/src
884487

exit
:~$
```

---

```
~$ sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends,remove-reinstreq linux-    image-3.13.0-101-generic
dpkg: linux-image-3.13.0-101-generic: dependency problems, but removing   anyway as you requested:
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-101-generic.

(Reading database ... 1223842 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-101-generic (3.13.0-101.148) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/prerm.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/prerm.d/dkms 3.13.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-101-generic
dkms: removing: bbswitch 0.7 (3.13.0-101-generic) (x86_64)
```

---

Uninstall Beginning

---

```
Module:  bbswitch
Version: 0.7
Kernel:  3.13.0-101-generic (x86_64)
```

---

```
Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

bbswitch.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.13.0-101-generic/extra/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-101-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-101-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-101-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT  is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-151-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-151-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-149-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-149-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-147-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-147-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-145-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-145-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-144-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-144-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-143-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-143-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-142-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-142-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-141-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-141-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-139-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-139-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-137-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-137-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-135-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-135-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-133-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-133-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-132-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-132-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-129-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-129-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-128-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-128-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-126-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-126-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-125-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-125-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-123-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-123-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-121-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-121-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-119-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-119-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-117-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-117-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-116-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-116-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-115-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-115-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-113-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-113-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-112-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-112-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-110-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-110-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-108-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-108-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-107-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-107-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-106-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-106-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-105-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-105-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-85-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-85-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-74-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
Purging configuration files for linux-image-3.13.0-101-generic    (3.13.0-101.148) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-101- generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-101-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-101-generic  /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-101-generic
```

---

sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends,remove-reinstreq linux-image

https://pastebin.com/TBFb9He9

---

`df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           390M  1.2M  389M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        19G   15G  3.7G  80% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G   51M  1.9G   3% /run/shm
none            100M   60K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1       823G   30G  752G   4% /home`

---

<05/12/18> I ran 6 with the full command and it returned over 142,000 so impossible to fully paste

I then tried to ran 7 but when I paste in Terminal and click on return Terminal crashes

Running `df -ih` gives ouput:

`bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             484K   545  483K    1% /dev
tmpfs            488K   554  487K    1% /run
/dev/sda1        1.2M  1.2M     0  100% /
none             488K     2  488K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             488K     3  488K    1% /run/lock
none             488K    56  488K    1% /run/shm
none             488K    29  488K    1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1         53M   40K   53M    1% /home`

When I logged on this morning updates on software ran - this has not happened since the low disk problem

<06/12/18> I can no longer log on.  PC starts and then gets to login page as normal. I enter login and 'return.' Instead of starting up it goes to a blank screen and then back to login page.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86802/discussion-on-question-by-taketime-low-disk-space-on-file-system).

Comment: Can he write on the chat even with his low rep?

Answer (score 2):

### First

Don't touch the [kernel](/questions/tagged/kernel), please, if you need space there's other places you can chop and vandalize. There's a reason you always have two version of the [kernel](/questions/tagged/kernel) in the system. And [apt](/questions/tagged/apt) always tells you to remove the old (3rd one) when you upgrade it.

### Second

[apt](/questions/tagged/apt) has space to fix itself, why didn't you answer `Y` *(yes)* when you ran `sudo apt install -f`?

Just run

```
sudo apt install -f
```

answer *yes*, and then run

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

---

Now if you want to make space...

Run the command as [root](/questions/tagged/root)

```
# du -h / -d 1 --exclude=/home
```

or with `sudo`

```
$ sudo du -h / -d 1 --exclude=/home
```

*(choose one)*

There we could see which directory uses more space, I bet and probably is `/var`. The moment you provide that feedback we can continue. Because the nature of you problem is space and I can't tell you to run commands that need space to work.

I could tell you, as an answer, to shrink `/home` to give more space to `/`, but that will need a lot of time and you could lose data in the process, so the best way *now* is to go step by step. You more than an answer need a solution and I can help you if you keep giving us the information.

One thing is sure, you have space to make. No way you need 19 Gigs in the root mount point

---

### 3

Run this command and paste the output please:

```
$ df -ih
```

And also as root run this

```
$ sudo su
# for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
# exit
```

---

### 4

Now (after you ran `du` on `/`) please run:

```
 $ sudo du -h /lib/ -d 1
```

Also, we started to see what's your problem. Looks like you are out of `inodes` on `/`. I need to check what's on `/lib` and then we can start to do some stuff

---

### 5

Run every command and paste each output separately:

```
$ sudo du -h /lib/modules/* -d 1

$ ls -la /lib/modules/

$ uname -r

$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image

$ awk -F\' '/menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Run as root

```
$ sudo su
# for i in /usr/*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
# exit
```

---

### 6

Run this

`sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends,remove-reinstreq linux-image-3.13.0-101-generic linux-image-3.13.0-105-generic linux-image-3.13.0-106-generic linux-image-3.13.0-107-generic linux-image-3.13.0-108-generic linux-image-3.13.0-110-generic linux-image-3.13.0-112-generic linux-image-3.13.0-113-generic linux-image-3.13.0-115-generic linux-image-3.13.0-116-generic linux-image-3.13.0-117-generic linux-image-3.13.0-119-generic linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic linux-image-3.13.0-123-generic linux-image-3.13.0-125-generic linux-image-3.13.0-126-generic linux-image-3.13.0-128-generic linux-image-3.13.0-129-generic linux-image-3.13.0-132-generic linux-image-3.13.0-133-generic linux-image-3.13.0-135-generic linux-image-3.13.0-137-generic linux-image-3.13.0-139-generic linux-image-3.13.0-141-generic linux-image-3.13.0-142-generic linux-image-3.13.0-143-generic linux-image-3.13.0-144-generic linux-image-3.13.0-145-generic linux-image-3.13.0-147-generic linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic linux-image-3.13.0-85-generic`

*I left the current and the last two versions*

[image: dpkg-console-command]
(paste the output)

---

### 7

If you ran **6**, you should have only 3 kernel entries now

Let's check, run this:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

---

### 8

Remove kernels leftovers (from 6)

`sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends,remove-reinstreq linux-image-extra-3.13.0-116-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-119-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-121-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-123-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-125-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-126-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-128-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-129-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-132-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-133-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-135-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-137-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-139-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-141-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-142-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-143-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-144-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-145-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-147-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-85-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-105-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-106-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-107-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-108-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-110-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-113-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-115-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-116-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-119-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-121-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-123-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-125-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-126-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-128-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-129-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-132-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-133-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-135-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-137-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-139-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-141-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-142-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-143-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-144-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-145-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-147-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-45-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-57-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-74-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-85-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-105-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-106-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-107-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-108-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-110-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-112-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-113-generic linux-modules-3.13.0-115-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-116-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-119-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-121-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-123-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-125-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-126-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-128-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-129-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-132-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-133-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-135-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-137-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-139-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-141-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-142-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-143-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-144-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-145-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-147-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-57-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-74-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-85-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-105-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-106-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-107-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-108-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-110-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-112-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-113-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-115-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-123 linux-headers-3.13.0-125 linux-headers-3.13.0-126 linux-headers-3.13.0-128 linux-headers-3.13.0-129 linux-headers-3.13.0-132 linux-headers-3.13.0-133 linux-headers-3.13.0-135 linux-headers-3.13.0-137 linux-headers-3.13.0-139 linux-headers-3.13.0-141 linux-headers-3.13.0-142 linux-headers-3.13.0-143 linux-headers-3.13.0-144 linux-headers-3.13.0-145 linux-headers-3.13.0-147 linux-headers-3.13.0-45 linux-headers-3.13.0-57 linux-headers-3.13.0-74 linux-headers-3.13.0-85 linux-headers-3.13.0-105 linux-headers-3.13.0-106 linux-headers-3.13.0-107 linux-headers-3.13.0-108 linux-headers-3.13.0-110 linux-headers-3.13.0-112 linux-headers-3.13.0-113 linux-headers-3.13.0-115`

Now, let's try

```
sudo apt install -f
```

---

---

### Pastebin | A Simple How-To

1. Copy the text from your computer. Include as much as you can.
2. Visit https://pastebin.com/
3. Paste your text into the big text box.
4. Click the submit button. The button where it says "Create New Paste"
5. The browser will take you to a new page.  The address (URL) of the page is unique. You can copy the address from the address bar, and share it with others, and they will be able to see the text you pasted.

Comment: apt has space to fix itself, why didn't you answer Y (yes) when you ran sudo apt install -f?  Because there is no room on the disk

Comment: This seems to be the issue.  Is there a work around?

Comment: I don't know if you don't understand english or didn't understood what I wrote or didn't understood what was the output of `df-h`. Because it clearly says `/dev/sda1        19G   18G  637M  97% /`, that means you have 637M left and with that space free `apt` can install what it needs. You always said NO when asked... say YES now and see what happen

Comment: And one thing, don't dump a log here, at least edit your question and add it there. And use the Preformatted text please