# How to fix double icons on plank (specifically Photoshop in wine)

Tags: plank

I'm trying to apply [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18/how-can-i-fix-the-fuzzy-google-chrome-icon-that-appears-in-plank) fix for my Photoshop,

I managed to find the file to edit at `~/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-psd.desktop` with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Adobe Photoshop CS6
MimeType=image/vnd.adobe.photoshop;
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/ian/.wine" wine start /ProgIDOpen Photoshop.Image.13 %f
NoDisplay=true
StartupNotify=true
Icon=6B73_Photoshop.0
```

I made this a question of its own because the linked question helped me until a certain extend, I couldn't figure how what would be equivalent to `StartupWMClass=Google-chrome-stable` here. What should I do?

Comment: @tim with your link I could make it work! we should put `StartupWMClass=Photoshop.exe`, should we close this question? or I should I post it as an answer?

Comment: @tim maybe should I just delete it?

Comment: Nowhere is Wine's default path for storing desktop files to be edited mentioned.

Comment: @fleamour I found the file I needed to edit on the specified location, maybe you can tell where to check here on comments?

Comment: Thx. I was looking under file system & not /home.