# How Can I Disable Chrome's New User Menu?

Tags: google-chrome

I upgraded Google Chrome to version 44.0.2403.89 and now I see new user menu.

[image]

Previously, there was a flag to disable it, but now there isn't. How can I remove this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Copy Chrome's .desktop file to your user's local applications folder using Terminal<sup>1</sup>:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open the copied .desktop file with:

   ```
   scratch-text-editor ~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
   ```
3. Find the line `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U`
4. Replace it with `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --disable-new-avatar-menu %U`
5. Save and close the file.
6. Restart Google Chrome and enjoy. ;-)

---

1. If you fixed Chrome's icon in Plank by [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/20/160) metod, skip this step.

Comment: --disable-new-avatar-menu no longer works in Chrome 46 https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/3qcben/looks_like_disablenewavatarmenu_no_longer_works/