# Intellij IDEA Blurry Second Icon on Plank

Tags: release-freya, plank, app-shortcuts

I am having an issue with keeping the Intellij IDEA app on my dock. It's the same with google-chrome but I haven't found any easy way to get rid of it. Whenever I open up the application, a blurry second icon pops up, just like the google-chrome icon issue. If anybody could help me, that would be amazing. Thank you!

The desktop file for this app is in `/usr/share/applications/jetbrains-idea.desktop`

The content is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Intellij IDEA
Icon=/opt/idea-IU-141.1532.4/bin/idea.png
Exec="/opt/idea-IU-141.1532.4/bin/idea.sh" %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
```

Also tried putting a copy into `~/.local/share/applications` but did not change anything. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds the like the desktop file needs to have the correct Window class, and it isn't currently matching. I'm not 100% sure how to find the Window class from the command line so I'll have to look that up and see if I can find you a fix that won't require installing anything else.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason deleting the `StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea` from `/usr/share/applications` and having the .desktop file with `StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea` at `~/.local/share/applications` did the trick.

Comment: Glad to know you got it to work. Remember to mark this as the accepted answer with the green tick.

Comment: The answer given here: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18/how-can-i-fix-the-fuzzy-google-chrome-icon-that-appears-in-plank?rq=1 should explain why this worked.