# Google Chrome no longer has an icon

Tags: icons, google-chrome

I've always been able to fix any issues I've had with Google Chrome's icon by setting a `StartupWMClass` [as described here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18/how-can-i-fix-the-fuzzy-google-chrome-icon-that-appears-in-plank), however as of today the icon broke completely, and `StartupWMClass` didn't solve it. It shows up as this now:

[image]

I ran `xprop | grep WM_CLASS` and the result, as expected, was `Google-chrome-stable`.

I've attempted purging `google-chrome-stable` and removing `~/.config/google-chrome/` but to no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** A reboot seemed to fix the issue, however I'll leave this question open if anyone has any idea what could've caused it, or how to fix it without having to reboot. This is Linux, not Windows.

Comment: I voted to close this as "unclear". If you're not longer able to reproduce the issue, it won't be able to be diagnosed.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll reopen it if I figure out how to reproduce it.

Comment: Try this: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/19705/12150