# How to solve broken Google Chrome icon?

Tags: release-loki, icons, google-chrome

[image]

Hi, can anyone guide me on how to solve this broken google chrome icon please?

Comment: This might help: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/google-chrome-no-longer-has-an-icon

Answer (score 4):

Just do `sudo apt -f install` after this. `dpkg -i` or `dpkg --install` doesn't install dependencies automatically.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the terminal navigate to `/usr/share/applications`

```
sudo scratch-text-editor google-chrome.desktop
```

scroll about halfway down to just above the `[Desktop Action NewWindow]` section

look for the Icon entry, it should look like this...

```
Icon=google-chrome
```

If not, change it to that.

After following the steps, the icon on the launcher may not update automatically. So, just remove the icon from the launcher first and then re-store icon on the dock after following the steps in this answer.

Comment: This is a good answer. Just want to add a bit here. After following the steps in the answer, the icon on the launcher may not update automatically. So, just remove the icon from the launcher first and then re-store icon on dock after following the steps in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try to reinstall google chrome, it's an easy way