# Google Chrome appears twice in slingshot

Tags: release-freya, icons, slingshot, google-chrome

I recently updated Google Chrome and
also encountered this [problem](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18/one-of-my-apps-has-a-second-fuzzy-icon-in-plank-how-can-i-workaround-this).

After doing a reboot I noticed that Google Chrome now appears twice searching for it in slingshot

---

**Edit:**

Attaching a screenshot

[image]

Comment: please ..will you post screen shot.=)

Comment: right now its not possible to take one if when using slingshot, I'll just take a photo.

Comment: Try to remove all files associated with Chrome from `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: suggestion : open `screenshot` and keep delay time of 7 or 10 seconds then click on `take screenshot` then automatically you can take screenshot :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I remove unwanted icons is use the program menulibre.

```
sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

That will give you a menu editor.

Open the Menu Editor and search for Chrome. Hide the icon and save your settings. Close and reopen the Application Bar and see if your duplicate is gone.

Comment: You can also use the brand-new AppEditor - a curated app. Does the same, just for the sake of completeness:  https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor.desktop