# Change specified app's icon

Tags: applications, plank, icons, settings

How can I change the icon for an specified app? I have installed Dota 2 but it shows Steam icon instead of Dota 2 icon, the right Doat 2 icons is shown when the game is running but not in plank. How can I change or fix this?

Comment: Hi Gocht, if one of these answers solved your issue, remember to mark it with the checkmark so it'll be promoted accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem. Initially I wasn't able to find the `Dota\ 2.desktop`. When I try the solution mentioned [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/2883/2856) using MainMenu I lost my app. So I created a back-up and reinstall.

I was using [elementaryPlus](https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus), and I found a nive Dota2 icons there, so I posted [an issue with my problem](https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus/issues/317) and I got support.

After I reinstalled Dota2 I found the `Dota\ 2.desktop` file and I replace the line:

```
Icon=steam
```

by

```
Icon=dota2
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the icon of dota 2 going to

> ~/.local/share/applications

and opening

> Dota 2.desktop

with a text editor like gedit or scratch, change this line

> Icon=steam

to this

> Icon=steam_icon_570

also, put this at the end of the file

> StartupWMClass=dota2

and save the file.

If your dota 2 icon is a gear, you can install elementary community icons from https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus, follow the instructions there and you will have a nice dota 2 icon.

---

Sorry for my english.

Sources:

https://steamcommunity.com/app/570/discussions/0/46476145209393444/

[One of my apps has a second, fuzzy icon in Plank. How can I workaround this?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18/one-of-my-apps-has-a-second-fuzzy-icon-in-plank-how-can-i-workaround-this)

Comment: I already have elementaryPlus installed (it's nice). I followed this steps to fix this https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus/issues/317 . But I still get a second icons when I run the app. I will give this solution a try. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2017, Steam doesn't create .desktop files for games.

Instead, create a file called "Dota 2.desktop" and use the following template:

`[Desktop Entry]
Name=Dota 2
GenericName=Steam game
Comment=Play this game
Exec=steam steam://rungameid/570
Icon=steam_icon_570
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Game;`

Once this is saved, you can find it in the launcher. You can then keep it in the dock.