# How can I change the icon of an application in the elementary OS

Tags: themes, icons

I am using elementary OS freya.

How can I change icon of a specific application in elementary OS.

Is it possible ?

Comment: I have a related question for an Steam app's icon https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2870/change-specified-apps-icon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**GUI** method to change icon of an application:(Using `nautilus` and `Main menu`)

**Method 1** : Using `alacarte`

1. Install *Main menu* (AKA `alacarte`)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install alacarte
   ```

[image: Imgur]

2. Open *Main menu*
3. Click on a program and select **properties**.
4. Click on app *icon*.
5. Browse for new icon and select <kbd>open</kbd>.
6. Close program *properties*
7. close *Main menu*

**Method 2**: Using `nautilus`

1. First we need to install `nautilus`

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nautilus
   ```
2. Now open terminal and run:

   ```
   sudo nautilus
   ```

   It will open your home directory.
3. Now navigate to `usr/share/applications/<what_ever_app>`
4. Right click on the app --> select properties -->

   Now *click* on app icon --> Now navigate to the location of required icon and select, then close.

   **For example**: I will change `icon` for `camera`

   Click on `camera` icon

---

> [image: Imgur]

---

I have a pic in `Downloads` folder. So navigate to that folder and change.

After,

---

> [image: Imgur]

---

> [image: Imgur]

---

**EDIT**:

Why should we use *root* :

If you don't use `root` there will be lock to icon,

[image: Imgur]

<sub>source for [method 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551627/problem-changing-icons-in-ubuntu-14-04)</sub>

Comment: This makes no sense. You should copy the file from /usr/share/applications into .local/share/applications then edit it there so you don't need root access and you're NOT modifying distro-provided files.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser Welcome to elementary OS- Excellent, your advice is more useful. Please post it as answer instead of comment. There will be many possible solutions for a problem.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser please avoid duplicate comments, your comment is suitable at another post (my opinion). Here I am using GUI method, in this case `root` access is to auto modify icon size.

Comment: yes but your method doesn't require root access if you copy the desktop file into .local then follow the steps on the copied file.

Comment: For GUI method need root acess otherwise the icon will have "lock"

Comment: @YetAnotherUser see my edit, =)

Comment: @YetAnotherUser: So I understand it right that the system first looks into the users folder (~/.local/share/applications) and uses these settings and if there is no correspondig file it will look into the global folder (/usr/share/applications/)? What happens, if there is an app update where - for any reason - the .desktop file needs to be updated too? The "local one" won't of course. Do I always have to compare the files after an update? Thank you.

Comment: @mazienho hello, any errors with this solution?

Comment: @mazienho yes. Usually desktop entries don't need updates anyway though.

Comment: Another thing to remember is that @Ravan 's method is system wide whereas copying the file to ~/.local/.. would be required for each user.

Answer (score 3):

To Change **specific App** icon:

1. I suppose, the icon which you want to place is `~/Downloads/[image.png]`
2. Open terminal and run the commands:

   ```
   nano /usr/share/applications/[appname].desktop
   ```

**Note** : If you don't know exact app name, use `ls -l`

3. Now replace `Icon=[path]` with `Icon=/home/[username]/Downloads/[image].png`

Now save and exist.

Comment: This makes no sense. You should copy the file from /usr/share/applications into .local/share/applications then edit it there so you don't need root access and you're NOT modifying distro-provided files.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser  Welcome to elementary OS-"makes no sense"-- why? If you have answer, please use "Post your answer" button instead of "Add comment". btw "should copy"--why? Why should I copy? with out copying I changed icon.

Comment: nicely explained!!

Comment: /usr/share/applications/ folder requires sudo.