# App icon is not merged in the dock

Tags: plank

When I open WebStorm app from app icon in the Dock, the app icon is not merged with existing app icon, it becomes a new icon (with grey color - please see in the picture).
How can I merge these app icon?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Try this: Remove all the WebStorm icons from the plank. Then go to Applications and right click on the WebStorm and click `Add to Dock`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sadly it does not work :(

Comment: You can also try to Add it to the dock after you open Webstorm. Again remove all the Webstorm icons from the plank, open webstorm and then right click on the Webstorm icon on the plank then Keep in Dock. Hope this helps! Btw, I see PhpStorm as well. Do this removing all the JetBrains icons from the plank.

Comment: Do all of your suggestions, also remove all JetBrains apps and then reinstalling them but it stay the same.

Comment: it should be reopened to clarify if this is or not the same problem. the question is different from the one to which this is supposed to be a duplicate (the second icon is not a double of the first) and the answer posted by the OP is very different from the definitive one of the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, there is a simple way to fix this: simple change the icon file from `webide.png` to `webide.ico`, or using this useful app to edit the menu: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/alacarte/

Comment: could you provide more details on this? your question was marked as duplicate but your answer is different from the one of the other question. A

Comment: In my case, I just rename the icon file from `webide.png` to `webide.ico` and it works.

Comment: If so, your problem seems different from the one to which this was flagged as duplicate (I flagged it to reopen, but I don't think it will be). - As  there is that question to which any other like yours will be flagged as duplicate I have tried to create an unified answer intended to sum up all variants: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4744/170

Comment: I'm curious: after renaming the icon: has the doubled icon completely disappeared (and you have one icon only as it should be) OR has it just got an image on it and now you have two similar when the program is open?

Comment: @cipricus: after renaming I have only one icon in the dock as it should be. I don't know if it can be worked with other apps or it just only works with PHPStorm.

Comment: thanks, that supports even more the idea that your Q is not a duplicate of the other, and an apparently similar problem has different causes and solutions