# Plank does not emerge icons

Tags: plank, icons

My issue is identical to [this one](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4021/app-icon-is-not-merged-in-the-dock), and it did solve my issue when I changed the logo from .png to .ico in .desktop. However, a restart/log-out session would render the solution void. As you can see from my screenshot below, I have the image extension as .ico, my StartupWMClass is also correct, but on the plank, there is still a Pocket Casts icon and a active grey gear icon. The two should merge.

If I edit the image in the .desktop file again, it became normal again. But I would have to do it every single time I log-out or restarts. It would be nice to have a permanent solution. The issue has been persistent since 5.0 months ago, I have tried different Pocket Casts linux apps and they all have this issue. I have not encounter this issue in any other app as of yet (I didn't install many).

I have Pocket Casts pinned, but it's the same if I unpinned and start from the application menu.

Thank you for any help

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the similar issue while setting up the AVD...

Here is my `AVD.desktop` file's *current* contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Android Virtual Device
Icon=/home/joe/.icons/AVD.png
Exec=/home/joe/Android/Sdk/emulator/./emulator @Q
Comment=Q @ Pixel_2
Categories=Development;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true;
#StartupWMClass=eOS
```

See the last line `#StartupWMClass=eOS`...? Try out the following:

- Run `xprop WM_CLASS` in the terminal and click on Pocket Casts and cross-check the same.
- Try Commenting the `StartupWMClass=` line.

Tip: you can reduce / truncate the `Comment=` section & uncomment the `#Icon=pocket-casts` while commenting the other `#Icon=...`

PS: I had to tweak here and there, checking out different combinations till I got it right.

Oh and one more thing make a copy of the `.desktop` file in `/home/<user>/.local/share/applications/` and make the edits there. And this is important *each* time you make a change to the `.desktop` file:

Re-add it to your dock: (*[credits](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1985/18392) @Cassidy James Blaede)

- Remove any existing Chrome launcher from your dock by secondary/right-clicking it and unchecking Keep in Dock, or simply drag the icon off of the dock.
- Open the app launcher (Applications) and drag the Chrome icon to your dock, or secondary/right-click it and select Add to Dock.

Comment: Wow, thank you, I think you solved this. I have googled this before posting the question and thus have checked the consistency with "xprop WM_CLASS", but I never place a `.desktop` file in `/home/<user>/.local/share/applications/`. I just did and restarted ... the icons merged!! I hope it's fine from now on. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Please upvote and mark it as answer if it worked for you.