# Fuzzy double icon for some applications on plank

Tags: release-hera, plank, icons

hope everyone is fine.

Before I start, I have to say that I have searched a lot for the solution and I have found [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18/one-of-my-apps-has-a-second-fuzzy-icon-in-plank-how-can-i-workaround-this), but it doesn't solve the problem, nor does it happen with Google Chrome.

What happens is that some applications, some installed from flathub and others as .appimage, are shown double in the Plank for a few seconds, until the blurred version remains and the good one disappears.

[image: Chromium]
[image: Calibre]

There are some more apps, but this are good examples. How can I fix this, is there a universal solution or do I have to go one by one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem.
I've also noticed that apps installed as flatpaks from the get-go are more likely not to have such behavior, but if you first installed the app from a repo than deleted it and installed the same, but from flathub this time, the issue with duplicated, blurry icons takes place. I remember back in the day of elementary OS 0.2 Luna there was the same kind of problem with regular Google Chrome installed from Google website.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to post this as an answer due to being a new user with no possibility to leave comments under others' posts.